# Testing AngularJS with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: angularjs, selenium, webdriver

Can anyone suggest if there is a lib or plugin that we can add as part of Selenium webdriver to automate Angular JS? I am looking for a tool so I can still use selenium webdriver.

Comment: Have you tried `Pytractor`, `Protractor`?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language binding you want to use. 
For Javascript, Protractor is a nature pick.
For c#, there are C# protractor plugin(https://github.com/bbaia/protractor-net)
For other languages, you can use the same approach as protractor-net does

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend Protractor tool for testing with selenium web driver.  Protractor implemented  to test site which is based on AngularJS.